# Writing deviceids of a disktype to an array

Tags: arrays, powershell

In PowerShell, I want to to write the driveletters (`deviceid`) of a `drivetype` (here type 2) to an array (variable `$letters`). The driveletters should be sorted like this:
$letters = @("a:", "b:") etc.

The line below I found works fine  with `win32_diskdrive`  but I am not able to add a drivetype.

```
$letters = Get-WmiObject win32_diskdrive | 
    Where {$_.interfacetype -Like "USB"} | 
    ForEach {Get-WmiObject -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF  {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID=`"$($_.DeviceID.replace('\','\\'))`"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition"} | 
    ForEach {Get-WmiObject -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID=`"$($_.DeviceID)`"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition"} |
    ForEach {$_.deviceid}
```

The next line below contains `Win32_LogicalDisk` instead of `win32_diskdrive` but I am not able to get a clean array-output like  `$letters = @("a:", "b:")`

```
$letters = Get-WMIObject Win32_LogicalDisk -filter DriveType=2 | Select ($_.deviceid)
```

gives

```
\\WIN7\root\cimv2:Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID="H:"
```

How can I combine `drivetype` with `win32_diskdrive` or how can I get only the "H:" with `Win32_LogicalDisk`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use `$_` in your `Select-Object` the way you have it. You would just put the properties you want to return. In your case: DeviceID. If you just want the strings from the USB devices you were close.

```
$letters = Get-WMIObject Win32_LogicalDisk -filter DriveType=2 | Where-Object {$_.Size -gt 0} | Select -ExpandProperty deviceid
```

`-ExpandProperty deviceid` will just return the string array instead of an object with a property of `DeviceID`

**Update from comments and other answer**

We can easily make a small update to ensure you get the drives that have a measureable size. We shall incorporate this while addressing your other answers plethora of `-replace` which is not required if you move the where clause and pay attention to the `-ExpandProperty deviceid` I tried to show you before.

Comment: Thanks, it works with your hint verry well with

    $letters = Get-WMIObject Win32_LogicalDisk -filter DriveType=2 | Select -Property deviceid 

Now I found out it shows also ejected but still plugged drives. How can I show only devices that have a (partition-) size?

Comment: Okay, find an answer by myselfe: Get-WMIObject Win32_LogicalDisk -filter DriveType=2 | Select -Property deviceid,size | where {$_.size}

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution. Works fine.

```
$letters = Get-WMIObject Win32_LogicalDisk -filter DriveType=2 | Select -Property deviceid, size | where {$_.size -gt 0}
$letters = $letters -replace '@{deviceid='
$letters = $letters -replace "size="
$letters = $letters -replace "}"
$letters = $letters -replace ""
$letters = $letters -replace '@{size='
$letters = $letters -replace '}'
$letters = $letters -replace '@{size='
$letters = $letters -replace ';'
$letters = $letters -replace '0'
$letters = $letters -replace '1'
$letters = $letters -replace '2'
$letters = $letters -replace '3'
$letters = $letters -replace '4'
$letters = $letters -replace '5'
$letters = $letters -replace '6'
$letters = $letters -replace '7'
$letters = $letters -replace '8'
$letters = $letters -replace '9'
$letters = $letters -replace ':'
$letters = $letters -replace ' '
```

Maybe theres an more easier way to replace all these things. But It works fine for me :-)